# Referencing a table more than once and getting related data

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

So I have a data model in Excel Power Pivot with 2 tables. The table "agreements", with the fields "contact_id_lessor", "contact_id_lessee" and "contact_id_witness"; and the table "contacts" with the fields "id" and "name". In the Diagram View I can connect the lessor, the lessee and the witness to a single instance of the table "contacts". The problem is I don't know how to get each of this party's "name" using DAX in the "agreements" table. The function RELATED() seems like the way to go, but there's no way to specify to the function the related field from the "agreements" table (lessor, lessee or witness), it should use to retrieve the data (contacts.name), and I can't find any other suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

While you can only have one ***active*** relationship between two tables (so between Leases and Contacts), you can have as many ***inactive*** relationships as you want. The difference is that you can't refer directly to related columns using an inactive relationship. You need to use syntax like this:

`CALCULATE([Measure],USERELATIONSHIP(FactTable[Column],DimensionTable[RelatedColumn]))`

Then just reuse your measure that uses CALCULATE to create more measures.

Comment: You lost me there, a bit @Pieter. Do I need to create a Measure with the contacts.name, in the contacts table, or how does it work?